# How to make Ariston Hotpoint FMG 863 SK washing machine to use more water

Tags: water, appliances, clothes-washer

Due to EU and US regulations, latest models of washing machines are really eco-friendly and use much less water thant their previous models. The problem is, this has to be countered by increasing the time to run the programs in order to keep the washing results good. Regular 60 C degree cotton program can take anything from three hours up to four. Often these models have also 1 hour fast wash, but the results are far from good if your clothes are even slightly more dirtier than your regular one day worn shirt. Some times it would just be really convinient to load the machine half full of water, run the fast program and still get good washing results.

There is a video on YouTube on how to hack Samsung Front Loader to use more water: https://youtu.be/2gYXdfg9TFg

Can I apply this information to hack my Ariston Hotpoint or are there any general tips some one can provide to make latest models of washing mascines to use more water?

Comment: These machines are designed to work with small amounts of water, I doubt adding more water will make them work better.   Is it possible that you're overloading the machine? Are you using HE (high efficiency) detergent?

Comment: tester is correct. The latest HE  washers only need little water. I believe the washers circuit board judges the water level by weight (I think) if that helps any.  For cleaner clothes add more detergent. Oxi-clean works very well with  the power of O2!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a way to do this, unless it is clearly written in the manual. Additional water in my Candy washing machine is used only for additional rinsing cycles and not for washing, therefore it even prolongs the time of washing, which is opposite of what I (and you, it seems) want.

I posted the similar question - whether there is a washing machine on the market that would allow me to low-level program it (e.g. to determine the amount of water as well). Apparently there isn't, but the feature is available in commercial washing machines, for example:

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Front-load-fully-programmable-industrial-50kg_60387387819.html

Note the specs, it says: USB port microprocessor enables to reprogram freely&easily by PC.

Perhaps your service/repair guy has this kind of access to your machine, but I highly doubt it, since it would probably make the energy certification invalid. The best is calling the authorized service shop and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

I learned just a thing: fast cycles should be avoided for stuff other than towels. Regular cycle is really better. If you really like fast cycles, I recommand to use liquid detergent as powder doesn't have enough time to dissolve properly.

Answer (score -1):

For Future Viewers:

You'd have to go to YouTube for an example & then an Appliance Repairer. There is indeed a cheat on many of them that's just turning a screw on the inlet valve governor. That's just one of several reasons why I won't buy a front loader & why many people go back to much quicker, cleaner & better top loaders.